# Loading indicator of buttons on the WB site is not animated on Safari

Tags: discussion, bug, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020

The loading indicator of buttons on the WB site is not animated on Safari.

### on Safari

- Browser: Version 14.0.1 (15610.2.11.51.10, 15610)

[image: on Safari]

```
      ^
```

### on Chrome (working example)

[image: on Chrome]

```
      ^
```

The "loading animation" I'm referring to is at the left side of the button.

Comment: What loading indicator?

Comment: On the left of the button

Comment: I see them on both in your screenshots. You mean that in Safari it's not moving?

Comment: The one on Chrome "moves in a circle". From a user's perspective, it feels weird.

Comment: So the bug report is misleading. The loading indicator is showing, just not animated.

Comment: Yep, I've updated the wording. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: Can you tell me if the loading indicators are working for you [over here](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/buttons/#loading) when you load them in Safari?

Comment: @YaakovEllis Yep, all of them work on that site.

Comment: @YaakovEllis I guess you just need to drop support for Safari all together ;)